# Split Archive file in cPanel

Tags: cpanel, backups

Here I am trying to backing up my email data.
When I create the zip, it is 8GB heavy file.
My plan is to zip and transfer online to box.
But box free account only allows 250mb per file.
So I am looking for a method to split my 8GB file into 250MB parts.

Can you give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use most of the popular archiver & compressors such as WinRAR or 7-Zip to "split" the file into 250MB archives.
I have used WinRAR to demonstrate the sort of thing you would need to do, it is all very similar and 7-Zip has it even more clearly labeled with "split archive" being an option. [image: example]

If you have access to a shell then you can "split" the archive.

```
mkdir emails
split -b 250m archive.zip emails/archive.zip.
```